# re.search surprisingly ends up None when ran under MSYS2 (and reading a file)?

Tags: python, regex, mingw-w64, msys2

So, this is the thing: I wrote a piece of Python code, a simple log file parser, at home, under Ubuntu Linux. The code worked perfectly.

Now, I come back to work, and here I have a Windows 10 machine, on which I've installed MSYS2, and I use its Pythons (both 2 and 3). Now, when I run the very same code on the very same file, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

... when the code encounters, say `m.group(1)`, which effectively means, the variable `m` is None.

Here is a test script, `test.py` that sets up the same line and the same regex - except, unfortunately, it does not reproduce the error:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys,os
import re

line = """TEST001 sample     1/00001: X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 1 TEMPC: 25.95°C
"""
m = re.search(r"""X: (\d+?) Y: (\d+?) Z: (\d+?) TEMPC: ([\d.]+?)°C""", line)
print(line, m, type(line))
```

Note that all line endings above are `\n` (that is, plain LF)

If I now run this with Pythons in MSYS2 - either the MSYS2 default ones (at `/usr/bin/python{2,3}`, that is, `C:\msys64\usr\bin\python{2,3}.exe`; or the Python 3 I have in MINGW64 shell, which is in `/mingw64/bin/python3` (that is, `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python3.exe`):

```
user@PC MSYS /tmp
$ python2 test.py
('TEST001 sample     1/00001: X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 1 TEMPC: 25.95\xc2\xb0C\n', <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x6ffffffcca8>, <type 'str'>)

user@PC MSYS /tmp
$ python3 test.py
TEST001 sample     1/00001: X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 1 TEMPC: 25.95°C
 <re.Match object; span=(28, 57), match='X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 1 TEMPC: 25.95°C'> <class 'str'>

user@PC MSYS /tmp
$ /mingw64/bin/python3 test.py
TEST001 sample     1/00001: X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 1 TEMPC: 25.95�C
 <re.Match object; span=(28, 57), match='X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 1 TEMPC: 25.95�C'> <class 'str'>
```

Notice here, that the MSYS2 Python2 cannot really print the UTF-8 character for degrees (which is expected); the MSYS2 Python3 *can* print this character - but the MINGW64 Python3 again cannot print this character, although it should ?!

Anyways - I run my actual work script in either MSYS2 or MINGW64 shell, explicitly by using `/mingw64/bin/python3`, since my actual work script needs to use `matplotlib` and `numpy`, and those can be installed only for MINGW64 shell ... However, there - as I mentioned - the program actually crashes, since the result of `m = re.search(...)` there, is that `m` becomes None.

---

EDIT: The code I have in my actual work script is:

```py
  with open(file_abspath, 'rt') as thelogfile:
    for line in thelogfile:
      if "something" in line: ...
      elif line.startswith("TEST001 sample"):
        m = re.search(r"""X: (\d+?) Y: (\d+?) Z: (\d+?) TEMPC: ([\d.]+?)°C""", line)
        print(line, m, type(line)) # added for debug
        ....
```

... and this printed out:

```
TEST001 sample     1/00001: X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 1 TEMPC: 25.95°C
 None <class 'str'>
```

... which is what I used in the above example.

---

Both my actual work script, and my file with data lines, have Unix line endings (`\n`, that is, LF) - and I've tried to simulate that in above `test.py`, by also having it with plain Unix line endings.

Would anyone have any idea, why does my actual work script reading a file line-by-line fail (that is, the result of `re.search` is None) when parsing the exact same line, which passes more-less without a problem in `test.py`, as shown in the above snippets?

Comment: My guess is that the line you showed us is _not_ the line which is causing the error.  Is it possible that a few lines don't match the pattern?

Comment: Thanks, @TimBiegeleisen - I added a snippet of my actual work script, with the added debug printout and what it printed - so I'm reasonably sure I've entered the same example line in my test script, as well... although, there's always the possibility I've made an error :)

Comment: What I'm saying is, you should try to add some logging while your entire script is actually running, to catch the error in flagrante delicto.

Comment: Maybe print out `repr(line)` instead of just `line`?  Perhaps there's an embedded tab or the like somewhere in there.

Comment: Thanks @JohnSzakmeister and @TimBiegeleisen  - I think I got it now; `pdb` was slightly more useful to me here, than just printouts of log statements (as it eventually turned out, there were no embedded invisible characters in the string) - and I managed to catch the error *in flagrante delicto* by copy-pasting stuff into pdb; please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I speculate that one or more of the lines in your input file, *not* the line you tested above, does not fit the pattern you are expecting.  Here is a suggested script you may try to flush out such non matching lines:

```
filepath = 'your_input.csv'
with open(filepath) as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    cnt = 1
    while line:
        m = re.search(r"""X: (\d+?) Y: (\d+?) Z: (\d+?) TEMPC: ([\d.]+?)°C""", line)
        if not m:
            print("Line #" + str(cnt) + " has a problem: " + line)
        line = fp.readline()
        cnt += 1
```

Assuming there are only a few offending lines, you might be able to edit the file by hand and fix the data.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I got it figured - let's first do this test: first, make a text file, `test.txt`, Unix (LF only) line endings:

```
TEST001 sample     1/00001: X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 1 TEMPC: 25.95°C
TEST002 sample     1/00002: X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 1 TEMPC: 25.95°C
TEST003 sample     1/00003: X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 1 TEMPC: 25.95°C
```

Then, let's try this script, `test2.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys,os
import re

with open('test.txt', 'rt') as thelogfile:
  for line in thelogfile:
    if "something" in line: pass
    elif line.startswith("TEST001 sample"):
      m = re.search(r"""X: (\d+?) Y: (\d+?) Z: (\d+?) TEMPC: ([\d.]+?)°C""", line)
      print(line, m, type(line)) # added for debug
```

Now, if I run this script in MINGW64 shell's Python 3 (so, `/mingw64/bin/python3`):

```
user@PC MINGW64 /tmp
$ python3 test2.py
TEST001 sample     1/00001: X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 1 TEMPC: 25.95°C
 None <class 'str'>
```

So, again, the match failed. Now, let's try debug with `pdb`:

```
user@PC MINGW64 /tmp
$ python3 -m pdb test2.py
> c:/msys64/tmp/test2.py(4)<module>()
-> import sys,os
(Pdb) b 11
Breakpoint 1 at c:/msys64/tmp/test2.py:11
(Pdb) r
> c:/msys64/tmp/test2.py(11)<module>()
-> m = re.search(r"""X: (\d+?) Y: (\d+?) Z: (\d+?) TEMPC: ([\d.]+?)▒C""", line)
(Pdb) p line
'TEST001 sample     1/00001: X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 1 TEMPC: 25.95°C\n'
(Pdb) n
> c:/msys64/tmp/test2.py(12)<module>()
-> print(line, m, type(line)) # added for debug
(Pdb) p m
None
(Pdb)
```

Ok, so here we can definitely see, it is the same text line as in OP, and the match object (returned from `re.search`) is None, so the problem is still present.

However, notice that, when PDB prints out the "m = re.search ..." line, the degree sign is corrupt:

```
▒C
```

... whereas if I print the line on its own, the degree sign is fine:

```
°C
```

So, suspecting that this may have something to do with encodings, I tried this in `pdb` - first, I copy-pasted the line that pdb dumped, with broken degree sign:

```
(Pdb) re.search(r"""X: (\d+?) Y: (\d+?) Z: (\d+?) TEMPC: ([\d.]+?)▒C""", line)
(Pdb)
```

There is, clearly, no return in this case. Then, I tried to run the same, except I copy pasted the `re.search` line from the source file directly, and into the terminal:

```
(Pdb) re.search(r"""X: (\d+?) Y: (\d+?) Z: (\d+?) TEMPC: ([\d.]+?)°C""", line)
<re.Match object; span=(28, 58), match='X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 1 TEMPC: 25.95°C'>
```

Nice, so here we got a match!

So, even if this sort of implies that the encoding of the *source* code file is not quite right - I found http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html and saw the `encoding` argument to `open()`, and so tried to employ it with the *data* file, instead - and this is the only change I needed to do with the above `test2.py`:

```py
with open('test.txt', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as thelogfile:
```

... and FINALLY, it started working:

```
user@PC MINGW64 /tmp
$ python3 test2.py
TEST001 sample     1/00001: X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 1 TEMPC: 25.95▒C
 <re.Match object; span=(28, 57), match='X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 1 TEMPC: 25.95▒C'> <class 'str'>
```

Why does this happen, specifically for Python3 in MINGW64 shell (and why it still has trouble printing proper UTF-8 to the shell, where otherwise the MSYS2 shell's Python3 has no problem with that), I cannot tell - but at least, I can get over the empty regex match return problem, by explicitly using `encoding='utf-8'` when opening the data file.